SwiftUI: Group can not be included in body, error: Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report
I am developing a demo to practice SwiftUI and Combine. I got an error when I added a group into a view as follows:
var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            // TODO: Add image view

            Group{
                
                switch viewModel.state{
                case .loading:
                    print("")
                case .failed(let error):
                    print("")
                case .sucess(let image):
                    print("")
                }
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                
                Text(article.title ?? "")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .semibold))
                Text(article.source ?? "")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .regular))
            }
        }
    }

The error:

Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report

Screenshot
It's strange because I did the same in another view and it works well.
By the way, I want to use a group because I want to use onAppear(perform: viewModel.loadImage(from: article.image)) as follows:
Group{
                
    switch viewModel.state{
        case .loading:
            print("")
        case .failed(let error):
            print("")
        case .sucess(let image):
            print("")
        }
    }.onAppear(perform: viewModel.loadImage(from: article.image))

My objective is to download one article image when the articleView(name of my class) appears. Can I use a function with parameters in onAppear? How can I download the article image when this articleView appears? Can I use task to replace
onAppear?
I find when I add viewModel.state, I will get the issue, but I use the same way in another view and I do not have this issue? can you help me? thanks you
I tried to better organize my var body: some View and could not find how to do this after searching the internet. The error Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report is not clear.

I find when I add viewModel.state, I will get the issue, but I use the same way in another view and I do not have this issue? can you help me? thanks you

you need to put let _ = in front, e.g.
let _ = print("")

It's because body is @ViewBuilder which is expecting you to declare View that are automatically returned however print doesn't return anything so you need to tell it you don't care about a View not being returned and use let _.
To answer your question about .task, yes with that you can remove the ObservableObject and the on.aAppear and just have:
.task(id: article.image) {
    self.state = await imageController.load(from: article.image))
}

imageController is a struct with the async func in it, usually it's an EnvironmentKey so it can be mocked for previews.
